# ggplot2: Degree Celsius Symbol in labeller with dev="tikz" option in knitr

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, tikz, tikzdevice

I want to put degree Celsius symbol in `ggplot2` `labeller`. MWE is given below with its output:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=mtcars, mapping = aes(x=drat, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(facets = ~cyl, labeller = as_labeller(c(`4` = "4 °C",`6` = "6 °C", `8` = "8 °C")))
```

[image]

However the same  strategy does not work when `dev="tikz"` option is used in `knitr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like one option when working with a tikz device is to write math in native latex. `\circ` is the degree symbol, so one of your labels could be `"$4^\\circ{C}$"`.

The following knits to a PDF with `dev = "tikz"` and shows the degree symbol:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, mapping = aes(x=drat, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(facets = ~cyl, 
         labeller = as_labeller(function(string) paste0("$", string, "^\\circ{C}$")))
```

To add more spacing between the number and degree symbol you can include `\\:` or `\\;` in the label.

```
labeller = as_labeller(function(string) paste0("$", string, "\\;^\\circ{C}$"))
```